# Devise+Omniauth, routes versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, devise

I have a model **Candidate** which is devise omniauthable (linkedin).

So far, my *routes.rb* looked like this :

```
namespace :v1 do
    devise_for :candidates, only: :omniauth_callbacks
    ...
end
```

Everything worked well till I had to add a new version :

```
namespace :v2 do
    devise_for :candidates, only: :omniauth_callbacks
    ...
end

namespace :v1 do
    devise_for :candidates, only: :omniauth_callbacks
    ...
end
```

With the current configuration, I get this error :

```
`set_omniauth_path_prefix!': Wrong OmniAuth configuration. If you are getting this exception, it means that either: (RuntimeError)
1) You are manually setting OmniAuth.config.path_prefix and it doesn't match the Devise one
2) You are setting :omniauthable in more than one model
3) You changed your Devise routes/OmniAuth setting and haven't restarted your server
```

It's kind of annoying since I want to be able to authenticate the candidate on both versions.

What can I do ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the exact SAME problem here. :(

Comment: I didn't, let me know if you find something ;)

Comment: YES!, I did find how to fix it. I'll post it as an answer soon.

Comment: any way you could post that solution?

Comment: @JoseE please do post!

Comment: Certainly, sir, give me a minute...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alright, let's recap a little bit here, **Devise doesn't allow you to call the** `devise_for` method inside a `scope` or a `namespace` route defined in the config/routes.rb file, right?

My namespace'd route looks like this:

```
namespace :api, constraints: { format: :json } do
  devise_for :users, skip: [ :registrations, :passwords, :confirmations ]
  resources :profiles, only: :show
end
```

And it works!

What did I do to make it work? the answer lies in the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.
Check out near the bottom of the File it says...

`# When using omniauth, Devise cannot automatically set Omniauth path,
 # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:`

The next commented line shows you an example, **uncomment that line and modify it** according to your needs, for my case(ie. for the namespaced route I have above) I have:

```
config.omniauth_path_prefix = "/api/users/auth"
```

And that's it! .... I did that and it all started to work perfectly!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks it's really helpful

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, although updating the path_prefix in the config file is a great workaround but it's a global update. On my side I use 2 different devise models and only one is namespaced do any of you guys have an idea of how to manage in a multiple model config ?

Comment: No clue, sir. Haven't used Devise in a Long time.